# Android unit test not mocked

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I followed [this guide](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) but I am stuck with this error:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor:
> testSaveJson (java.lang.RuntimeException: Method put in
> org.json.JSONObject not mocked. See
> https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support
> for details.

I modified by Gradle build like the guide says but it doesn't make a difference

```
testOptions { 
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

Comment: We need more information. Add some code, explain what you're trying to achieve. Unit test a JSON (de)serializer?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

JSON is bundled up with the Android SDK, so you'll just be hitting a stub. You can pull in a JSON jar, which will provide real objects to use.

To do this, you'll need to add this to your build.gradle:

```
testImplementation 'org.json:json:20140107'
```

Alternatively, you can download and include the jar.

```
testCompile files('libs/json.jar')
```

Note that the latest version of JSON is built for Java 8, so you'll need to grab [20140107](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107)
You may also need to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Seems you can now pull using Gradle, so `testCompile 'org.json:json:20140107'` is fine.

Comment: Why do you say that pulling from maven central doesn't work?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it seems to be working again, so I'll update the answer

Comment: You should use THIS version : `org.json:json:20080701`, which matches the Android version. In this version, `getString()` returns null when value is json is null, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: @NicolasCornette to which Android version are you referring?

Comment: @BenPearson this is true on all android versions

Comment: Simply including this in build.gradle does not seem to import the correct libraries - I'm still getting the 'not mocked' error. What needs to be done to use the explicit library modules?

Comment: Never mind - turns out a clean/ rebuild fixed the problem.

Comment: It works, but as @tbm write - only after clean and rebuild. Can you add it to the answer?

Comment: Is it required for Test Implementation only?

Comment: Latest version available is 20190722

Answer (score 10):

I think you trying to run tests with `org.json.JSONObject` which is part of `Android Framework` on pure `jUnit`.

From docs:

> The android.jar file that is used to run unit tests does not contain any actual code - that is provided by the Android system image on real devices. Instead, all methods throw exceptions (by default).
>
> We are aware that the default behavior is problematic when using classes like Log or TextUtils and will evaluate possible solutions in future releases.

You need to emulate Android environment you can use for this purpose [Robolectric](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric) or InstrumentationTests

Comment: So there is no way to use JSON in plain Junit tests?

Comment: Using Robolectric did the job for me. Interestingly the error message appeared after we upgraded to Android Studio Arctic Fox with AGP 7.0, with Android Studio 4.2 and AGP 4.2 we had no problem.

Answer (score 9):

You need to add the following to the build.gradle:

```
android {
  // ...
  testOptions { 
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
//...
    testImplementation 'org.json:json:20180813'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for the problem in if you're using Kotlin DSL:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.isReturnDefaultValues = true
}

testImplementation("org.json:json:20210307")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
android {


testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
} }

dependencies {
testImplementation libs.leakCanaryNoOp
testImplementation tests.jUnit
testImplementation tests.mockito
testImplementation(tests.mokitoKotlin) {
    exclude group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin", module: "kotlin-stdlib"
    exclude group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin", module: "kotlin-runtime"
    exclude group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin", module: "kotlin-reflect"
    exclude group: "org.mockito", module: "mockito-core"
}
testImplementation tests.powerMock
testImplementation tests.powerMockApiMockito
testImplementation (tests.robolectric) {
    exclude group: 'org.robolectric', module: 'robolectric-resources:'
}
testImplementation (tests.robolectricShadowsSupport){
    exclude group: 'org.robolectric', module: 'robolectric'
}
kaptTest libs.daggerCompiler
```

}

Comment: Can we have more explanations about this?