# How its the correct way to test a serielize method inside a class?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I have this method inside a class, It serialize in a JSONObject the attributes of the class, quite simple:

```
public String serialize(){
    JSONObject wifiToAddJson = null;
    try {
        wifiToAddJson = new JSONObject();
        wifiToAddJson.put("wifi_ssid", wifi_ssid);
        wifiToAddJson.put("wifi_password", wifi_password);
        wifiToAddJson.put("latitude", wifi_LatLng.latitude);
        wifiToAddJson.put("longitude", wifi_LatLng.longitude);
        wifiToAddJson.put("name", name);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(new MyJSONException(TAG + e.getMessage()));
    }
    return wifiToAddJson.toString();
}
```

I want to test if this method it's ok, by asking all the fields' values. 
I thought to do it with a test like this:

```
@Test
public void testSerialize(){
    String wifiSerialized = wiFiToAdd.serialize();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(wifiSerialized);

        String ssid = (String) jsonObject.get("wifi_ssid");
        String password = (String) jsonObject.get("wifi_password");
        String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
        String latitude = (String) jsonObject.get("latitude");
        String longitude = (String) jsonObject.get("longitude");

        assertEquals("WIFI_TEST", ssid);
        assertEquals("wifiTest", password);
        assertEquals("WiFi Pruebas", name);
        assertEquals("40.420088", latitude);
        assertEquals("-3.688810", longitude);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But here comes the problem:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method put in org.json.JSONObject not mocked. See https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support for details.
    at org.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java)
    at com.wiffinity.easyaccess.model.wifi.WiFiToAdd.serialize(WiFiToAdd.java:32)
    at com.wiffinity.easyaccess.model.wifi.WiFiToAddTest.testSerialize(WiFiToAddTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Google docs say:

The android.jar file that is used to run unit tests does not contain any actual code - that is provided by the Android system image on real devices. Instead, all methods throw exceptions (by default). This is to make sure your unit tests only test your code and do not depend on any particular behaviour of the Android platform (that you have not explicitly mocked e.g. using Mockito). If that proves problematic, you can add the snippet below to your build.gradle to change this behavior:

```
android {
// ...

    testOptions { 
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}
```

I don't want to change the total behaviour of my tests. How can I test the method in a clean way and not changing the behaviour of tests?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35675861/3032209

Answer (score 1):

You could cut your `serialize` method in 2:

```
public void serializeInto(JSONObject target) throws JSONException {
    wifiToAddJson.put("wifi_ssid", wifi_ssid);
    wifiToAddJson.put("wifi_password", wifi_password);
    wifiToAddJson.put("latitude", wifi_LatLng.latitude);
    wifiToAddJson.put("longitude", wifi_LatLng.longitude);
    wifiToAddJson.put("name", name);
}

public String serialize(){
    JSONObject wifiToAddJson = null;
    try {
        wifiToAddJson = new JSONObject();
        serializeInto(wifiToAddJson);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(new MyJSONException(TAG + e.getMessage()));
    }
    return wifiToAddJson.toString();
}
```

And then test the first one with a mocked `JSONObject` and the second one with a mock of your class (just verifying that the method `serialize` was called).

I am not entirely satisfied with this answer because you won't reach 100% coverage with it, and I feel like it degrades code readability a bit.

Comment: I am not sure to change a "working" public method in two public methods only to test it. It is a possibility of course. I'll keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your build.gradle file:

```
testCompile 'org.json:json:20160810' // org.json is included with Android, but Android.jar can not be used from unit tests
```

It will make your unit tests use the JSON-library directly, and not the one included in Android.

See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30759769/460318) for more details.