# Get null when generating JSONObject with String

Tags: java, android, json

I'm now trying this code with JUnit.

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"name\":\"foo\",\"id\":\"2\"}");
    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
    Log.d(TAG, "name = " + name);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm now testing put break point line at "Log.d...", but jsonObject always null.
What is my mistake? This code is no problem on actual device.

Comment: It looks good, actually.

Comment: its working.. can you add exception or more details..

Comment: I find that this code works fine on actual device. This is a problem on debugging with JUnit.

Comment: yes, Its working..!!!

Comment: Completely working . No any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should get an error if it's improperly formatted JSON, so not sure why it would be null.

Just in case, though, I would personally avoid the need to escape the quotes in the string and individually put each key-value.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("name", "foo");
jsonObject.put("id", "2");
```

Comment: I tried this code on JUnit, and I could find this jsonObject is also null.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related with my JUnit emviroment.
I use this configuration.

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

When I change this option false, this test invoke error like

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method put in org.json.JSONObject not mocked.
```

I could find a test using JSONObject can not be tested with usual way.
It's lucky.

Thank you everyone comment to me.

Comment: I can test my program calling JSONObject by importing JSON library. Useful information is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402155/android-unit-test-not-mocked

Comment: Using robolectric is better solution. It also works fine for me, and no need to import JSON lib.

Answer (score 0):

Android JSON API is part of android its not part of Java API.
i.e they are not available to run on JVM they run on android environment.

If you want to use JSON API for unit testing you need to integrate below dependency in `build.gradle` file in `android studio`

```
testImplementation 'org.json:json:20140107'
```