# Why am I getting a null object when creating a JSONObject from string?

Tags: java, android, json

I've written a Java Method for an Android Studio (3.0.1) project that creates a JSONObject from a String. Now I've written a JUnit test to test that the JSON object is correct.

The problem is always that the JSONObject is NULL.

For example, I tried running the following code:

```
String response = "{\"songs\":\"title\"}";
System.out.println(response);
JSONObject submitPlaylistResponse = new JSONObject(response);
System.out.println(submitPlaylistResponse.toString());
```

The output is:

```
{"songs":"title"}
null
```

Why is my JsonObject still null? What am I missing? I feel like I'm missing something trivial/simple.

Comment: If you replace JSONObject submitPlaylistResponse = new JSONObject(response); with JSONObject submitPlaylistResponse = new JSONObject("{\"songs\":\"title\"}"); what do you get ?

Comment: What is your import for JSONObject

Comment: try this one `System.out.println(submitPlaylistResponse.getString("songs"));`

Comment: @android_Muncher: same thing - null object. Import is import org.json.*;

Comment: @G.Dator: same issue occurs.

Comment: try my answer below sir

Comment: What is your import statement for JSONObject. The answer depends on which lib you are using.

Comment: It isn't null. Otherwise you would get a `NullPointerException` calling `toString()` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After viewing **JSONObject** [code](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java) I found this:

```
public String toString() {
   return "null";
}
```

As you see, method always returns "null" string not null object.
In this case, if the task is to check the correctness of your **JSONObject** you can follow @G.Dator answer or use *String toString (int indentSpaces)*.

[See](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) also.

Comment: looks like `toString(int indentFactor)` is also broken. How in the world does someone introduce a bug like this when it worked in previous versions?! I guess people rewrite classes. This is why I keep 3rd party libraries to a minimum (though `org.json` was the one I had the most trust in until now).

Answer (score 1):

Add below line to build.gradle dependencies

```
testImplementation 'org.json:json:20190722'
```

Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402155/android-unit-test-not-mocked) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using wrong library. Check your import. It must be like this. org.json.JSONObject;
I've checked your code and it's working on my android studio 2.3