# jsonarray from string returning as null

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin

This single line of snippet of converting string to JSONArray is returning as null, any ideas?

```
JSONArray("""[{"id":1,"first":"John","last":"Doe"}]""")
```

[image]

Here are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.4'

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
}
```

---

Subsequent issues. Calling localhost from SUT using JUnit.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you must be running unitTests which are present under module/tests in Android project.

If you try to use or access the Android related code in JUnit tests then it is not expected to work until and unless you've not added the following line of code in your `build.gradle` file of the module.

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
}
```

And once you add the above configuration, any access to Android methods is expected to return their default value, no matter what you're passing to them.

Anything related to android tests needs to be written under `androidTest`

For more info.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.-

Comment: you are right, the class is a SUT and is running under a test, however, I'm still getting null, still checking if I got everything right, any ideas?

Comment: please check my dependencies too

Comment: after some research I have added in `testImplementation 'org.json:json:20140107'`, however, there's another problem, I'm testing on localhost via `http://10.0.2.2:8080` (see second screenshot), I'd appreciate your input there as well. Thanks

Comment: It seems your project is not able to fetch the dependency. Download it manually for now and then try to test it once if that is helping you resolve your issue.

Do download manually and use that as a dependency refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402155/android-unit-test-not-mocked/30036602

Comment: I revisited the project 2 days after, added the jar as per the suggested link, it worked, I commented the local jar path to force it to fail and it still worked, deleted the jar file from libs and its continuing working, not sure what happened.